# Join list from two list in Java Object in stream

Tags: java

I have two list on two Class where id and month is common

```
public class NamePropeties{
    private String id;
    private Integer name;
    private Integer months;
}


public class NameEntries {
    private String id;
    private Integer retailId;
    private Integer months;
}
```

List NamePropetiesList = new ArrayList<>();
List NameEntries = new ArrayList<>();

Now i want to `JOIN` two list (like `Sql` does, `JOIN ON month and id` coming from two results) and return the data in new list where month and id is same in the given two list.

if i will start iterating only one and check in another list then there can be a size iteration issue.

i have tried to do it in many ways but is there is any stream way?

Comment: Do you have a class that holds the result? Because otherwise this is moot.

Comment: yes i do have...both classes hold results in a list

Comment: What Polygnome ment is that with an sql join you'd get a set of rows whose columns are the columns from the two tables. The Java equivalent would be a List of objects whose fields are the fields from the two classes. Do you have such a class? Ideally it should have a constructor that takes an instance of each class

Comment: Well, you could use streaming but I'm not sure that would help a lot. If you just use the lists you would have to use nested loops and thus get O(n^2) performance. Instead you might want to iterate once over one list, build a map based on the "join" elements ("id" I guess) and then iterate over the second list and pull the "join" element from the list. That way you'd get O(n) performance. - Btw, building the map could be done by using `.collect(Collectors.toMap(...))` on a stream but you can as well use a plain old foreach loop.

Comment: @Thomas if i will iterate over one list and build map..then check on second list then in that case how can i make cobination of month and id as a 'key' to check on another list?

Comment: Yes that could be the case but you'd have to handle that anyway. If you want something like an outer join you'd need to check what data from the map didn't get used. nested loops would have the same problem though.

Comment: @Thomas if i will iterate over one list and build map..then check on second list then in that case how can i make combination of month and id (as i have to check on this combination) as a 'key' to check on another list?

Comment: @jacob Do the list have different sizes? i.e. is one list much bigger than the other one?

Comment: Well, build a "key" class that can take both (and don't forget to override equals() and hashCode()).

Comment: @Aaron yes i have that class which will bind those two classes in one, but we need to merge two data first on conditions

Comment: @fps that might be irrelevant if the lists might have the same size but different elements, e.g. [A, B, C] vs. [B, C, D].

Comment: @fps it can be random... we cant say

Comment: @Thomas yes i think doing that map then checking on another would be the best solution.. better than stream as it will give O(n2)

Comment: @Thomas it's not irrelevant, as I will show in my answer

Comment: @fps the beauty of this question is the size of the list of any of those we don't know otherwise i would have just iterated over the larger list... but again we can do that.. but it will be be lengthy and messy solution

Answer (score 1):

The general idea has been sketched in the comments: iterate one list, create a map whose keys are the attributes you want to join by, then iterate the other list and check if there's an entry in the map. If there is, get the value from the map and create a new object from the value of the map and the actual element of the list.

It's better to create a map from the list with the higher number of joined elements. Why? Because searching a map is `O(1)`, no matter the size of the map. So, if you create a map from the list with the higher number of joined elements, then, when you iterate the second list (which is smaller), you'll be iterating among less elements.

Putting all this in code:

```
public static <B, S, J, R> List<R> join(
    List<B> bigger, 
    List<S> smaller,
    Function<B, J> biggerKeyExtractor,
    Function<S, J> smallerKeyExtractor,
    BiFunction<B, S, R> joiner) {

    Map<J, List<B>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    bigger.forEach(b -> 
        map.computeIfAbsent(
                biggerKeyExtractor.apply(b),
                k -> new ArrayList<>())
            .add(b));

    List<R> result = new ArrayList<>();
    smaller.forEach(s -> {
        J key = smallerKeyExtractor.apply(s);
        List<B> bs = map.get(key);
        if (bs != null) {
            bs.forEach(b -> {
                R r = joiner.apply(b, s);
                result.add(r);
            }
        }
    });

    return result;
}
```

This is a generic method that joins bigger `List<B>` and smaller `List<S>` by `J` join keys (in your case, as the join key is a *composite* of `String` and `Integer` types, `J` will be `List<Object>`). It takes care of duplicates and returns a result `List<R>`. The method receives both lists, functions that will extract the join keys from each list and a joiner function that will create new result `R` elements from joined `B` and `S` elements.

Note that the map is actually a multimap. This is because there might be duplicates as per the `biggerKeyExtractor` join function. We use [`Map.computeIfAbsent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#computeIfAbsent-K-java.util.function.Function-) to create this multimap.

You should create a class like this to store joined results:

```
public class JoinedResult {

    private final NameProperties properties;
    private final NameEntries entries;

    public JoinedResult(NameProperties properties, NameEntries entries) {
        this.properties = properties;
        this.entries = entries;
    }

    // TODO getters
}
```

Or, if you are in Java 14+, you might just use a record:

```
public record JoinedResult(NameProperties properties, NameEntries entries) { }
```

Or actually, any `Pair` class from out there will do, or you could even use `Map.Entry`.

With the result class (or record) in place, you should call the `join` method this way:

```
long propertiesSize = namePropertiesList.stream()
    .map(p -> Arrays.asList(p.getMonths(), p.getId()))
    .distinct()
    .count();
long entriesSize = nameEntriesList.steram()
    .map(e -> Arrays.asList(e.getMonths(), e.getId()))
    .distinct()
    .count();

List<JoinedResult> result = propertiesSize > entriesSize ? 
    join(namePropertiesList, 
         nameEntriesList, 
         p -> Arrays.asList(p.getMonths(), p.getId()),
         e -> Arrays.asList(e.getMonths(), e.getId()),
         JoinedResult::new)                                    :
    join(nameEntriesList, 
         namePropertiesList, 
         e -> Arrays.asList(e.getMonths(), e.getId()),
         p -> Arrays.asList(p.getMonths(), p.getId()),
         (e, p) -> new JoinedResult(p, e));
```

The key is to use generics and call the `join` method with the right arguments (they are flipped, as per the join keys size comparison).

Note 1: we can use `List<Object>` as the key of the map, because all Java lists implement `equals` and `hashCode` consistently (thus they can safely be used as map keys)

Note 2: if you are on Java9+, you should use `List.of` instead of `Arrays.asList`

Note 3: I haven't checked for neither `null` nor invalid arguments

Note 4: there is room for improvements, i.e. key extractor functions could be *memoized*, join keys could be reused instead of calculated more than once and multimap could have `Object` values for single elements and lists for duplicates, etc

Answer (score 1):

If performance and nesting (as discussed) is not too much of a concern you could employ something along the lines of a crossjoin with filtering:

Result holder class

```java
public class Tuple<A, B> {
    public final A a;
    public final B b;

    public Tuple(A a, B b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Join with a predicate:

```java
public static <A, B> List<Tuple<A, B>> joinOn(
    List<A> l1,
    List<B> l2,
    Predicate<Tuple<A, B>> predicate) {
    return l1.stream()
        .flatMap(a -> l2.stream().map(b -> new Tuple<>(a, b)))
        .filter(predicate)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Call it like this:

```java
List<Tuple<NamePropeties, NameEntries>> joined = joinOn(
    properties,
    names,
    t -> Objects.equals(t.a.id, t.b.id) && Objects.equals(t.a.months, t.b.months)
);
```